# Incorrect key file for table error on outer join logic in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I have a lengthy MySQL query I'm attempting to use a FULL OUTER JOIN on, which does not exist in MySQL:

```
select c.cat_id,c.cat_name as cat_name, 
 c.cat_desc, c.cat_image, mi.filename, 
 l.link_id, l.user_id, l.address,l.city, 
 l.country,l.link_created,l.link_desc, 
 l.email,l.fax,l.link_hits, l.link_modified,
 l.link_name,l.postcode, l.price,l.link_rating, 
 l.state,l.telephone,l.link_votes,
 l.website, l.link_id, l.link_visited, cf.value
from j25_mt_cats as c,
j25_mt_links as l 
LEFT JOIN j25_mt_cfvalues AS cf ON (cf.link_id = l.link_id),
j25_mt_images AS mi,
j25_mt_cl as cl
where cf.cf_id = 40 and cl.link_id = l.link_id 
 AND mi.link_id = l.link_id AND mi.ordering < 2  
 AND c.cat_id = cl.cat_id and c.cat_published = 1 
 AND c.cat_approved = 1 and l.link_published = 1 and l.link_approved = 1
ORDER BY RAND() DESC;
```

The LEFT JOIN above is where I'm looking to instead use FULL OUTER JOIN logic. I understand it has to use multiple JOINs with UNION, but my attempts have resulted in various syntax errors.

What's the correct syntax to change the above to a FULL OUTER JOIN logic?

I'm trying this:

```
select c.cat_id,c.cat_name as cat_name, 
 c.cat_desc, c.cat_image, mi.filename, 
 l.link_id, l.user_id, l.address,l.city, 
 l.country,l.link_created,l.link_desc, 
 l.email,l.fax,l.link_hits, l.link_modified,
 l.link_name,l.postcode, l.price,l.link_rating, 
 l.state,l.telephone,l.link_votes,
 l.website, l.link_id, l.link_visited, cf.value
from j25_mt_cats as c,
j25_mt_links as l 
LEFT OUTER JOIN j25_mt_cfvalues AS cf ON (cf.link_id = l.link_id),
j25_mt_images AS mi,
j25_mt_cl as cl
UNION ALL
select c.cat_id,c.cat_name as cat_name, 
 c.cat_desc, c.cat_image, mi.filename, 
 l.link_id, l.user_id, l.address,l.city, 
 l.country,l.link_created,l.link_desc, 
 l.email,l.fax,l.link_hits, l.link_modified,
 l.link_name,l.postcode, l.price,l.link_rating, 
 l.state,l.telephone,l.link_votes,
 l.website, l.link_id, l.link_visited, cf.value
FROM j25_mt_cats as c,
j25_mt_links as l
RIGHT OUTER JOIN j25_mt_cfvalues AS cf ON cf.link_id = l.link_id,
j25_mt_images AS mi,
j25_mt_cl as cl
where cf.cf_id = 40 and cl.link_id = l.link_id 
 AND mi.link_id = l.link_id AND mi.ordering < 2  
 AND c.cat_id = cl.cat_id and c.cat_published = 1 
 AND c.cat_approved = 1 and l.link_published = 1 and l.link_approved = 1
 AND cf.link_id IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND() DESC;
```

But it takes minutes to run, then returns `#126 - Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_4f82_0.MYI'; try to repair it`
 when I think I'm closer to the correct syntax. The disk isn't full or even close. Nor is this a table, it's just a query I'm running in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: You should see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql

Comment: @ThịtBòTái Yes, that's the syntax I tried and I'm getting syntax errors and the sort. Edited my attempt into question.

Comment: hi @Zeno, ur table is crashed, please repair it, this is the references link that u can refer, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/repair-table.html

Comment: Do **not** mix implicit joins (using `,` and `where` conditions) with explicit joins (using `JOIN` keywords)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Does that mean I need to write this from scratch?

Comment: No, just get do your joins in a consistent manner (preferably everything using explicit `JOIN`s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs, tipically, when you fill the temporary directory, and in your case, probably, your query creates a huge temporary file.

Apart optimize your query, try monitoring your partition where the temporary directory is located  `show variables like 'tmpdir';` during your query.

Comment: Yep, 3GB file being created in `/tmp` confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

if possible please provide table design , sample column, the problem of unknown column i guess is because of your bottom join missing some cast

```
select c.cat_id,c.cat_name as cat_name, 
c.cat_desc, c.cat_image, mi.filename, 
l.link_id, l.user_id, l.address,l.city, 
l.country,l.link_created,l.link_desc, 
l.email,l.fax,l.link_hits, l.link_modified,
l.link_name,l.postcode, l.price,l.link_rating, 
l.state,l.telephone,l.link_votes,
l.website, l.link_id, l.link_visited, cf.value
from j25_mt_cats as c,
j25_mt_links as l 
LEFT OUTER JOIN j25_mt_cfvalues AS cf ON (cf.link_id = l.link_id)
```

//you mi is missng here [Start]

```
j25_mt_images AS mi,
j25_mt_cl as cl
where cf.cf_id = 40 and cl.link_id = l.link_id 
AND mi.link_id = l.link_id AND mi.ordering < 2  
AND c.cat_id = cl.cat_id and c.cat_published = 1 
AND c.cat_approved = 1 and l.link_published = 1 and l.link_approved = 1
AND cf.link_id IS NULL
```

// END

```
UNION ALL
select c.cat_id,c.cat_name as cat_name, 
c.cat_desc, c.cat_image, mi.filename, 
l.link_id, l.user_id, l.address,l.city, 
l.country,l.link_created,l.link_desc, 
l.email,l.fax,l.link_hits, l.link_modified,
l.link_name,l.postcode, l.price,l.link_rating, 
l.state,l.telephone,l.link_votes,
l.website, l.link_id, l.link_visited, cf.value
```

//u forgot to define c,l,cf at here

```
FROM j25_mt_cats as c, j25_mt_links as l 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN j25_mt_cfvalues as cf ON cf.link_id = l.link_id,
j25_mt_images AS mi,
j25_mt_cl as cl
where cf.cf_id = 40 and cl.link_id = l.link_id 
AND mi.link_id = l.link_id AND mi.ordering < 2  
AND c.cat_id = cl.cat_id and c.cat_published = 1 
AND c.cat_approved = 1 and l.link_published = 1 and l.link_approved = 1
AND cf.link_id IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND() DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, strangely enough it's the `mi` one I'm getting an error on. Updated my question.

Comment: top query missing mi~

Comment: Weird, that makes it try to query for minutes then errors with `#126 - Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_4f82_0.MYI'; try to repair it`